# Possible to open an e-mail created in php in Outlook?

Tags: php, outlook

I am trying to create a file that is essentially an e-mail with headers and all in php and then present it to the user. The User would open it in outlook and then send.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. *.eml and *.msg are plaintext files with proper encoding and headers. If you can create message [according to spec](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822.html), it will be read by Outlook.

Comment: Thanks, the spec is very extensive but I figured out that you can leave out everything except for the essentials and outlook will still accept it.

Comment: Do not forget encoding, since without encoding you will have problems with national characters.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to write a file in [.msg format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc463912.aspx).

The only thing I could find is a commercial .NET library, [Aspose](http://www.wwwcoder.com/Forums/tabid/233/forumid/2/postid/4486/view/topic/Default.aspx), but nothing using PHP.